# Diagonals of regular heptagon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

If $a,b$ are the length of unequal diagonals of a regular heptagon with side $c$, then Prove that $c(a+b)=ab$ .

Comment: This site works better if you don't just dump questions here with no indication of where they come from, why you are interested in them, what progress you have made on them, where you have gotten stuck, and so on, and so forth.

Comment: duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2702572 where you will find an answer of mine.

Comment: Find a quadrilateral on four of the vertices a heptagon and apply Ptolemy's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4, A_5, A_6, A_7$ be the vertices of the regular heptagon (is it seven-gon? I hope I got the number of edges right :)), listed in cyclic order. Let $k$ be the circle circumscribed around the heptagon. Triangle $A_1A_2A_5$ is isosceles with $A_1A_5 = A_2A_5 = a$ (follows by regularity and hence symmetry of the heptagon). Triangle $A_1A_3A_5$ is also isosceles with $A_1A_3 = A_3A_5 = b$ again by regularity and hence symmetry of the heptagon. By regularity of the heptagon, $A_1A_2 = A_2A_3 = c$. Finally, the quadrilateral $A_1A_2A_3A_5$ is inscribed in the circle $k$ and therefore it satisfies Ptolemy's theorem, according to (one direction of) which
$$A_1A_2 \cdot A_3A_5 + A_2A_3 \cdot A_1A_5 = A_1A_3 \cdot A_2A_5$$ or written in $a, b, c$ notations
$$cb + c a = b a$$ which is exactly the relation $c(a + b) = ab$.